# c# asynchronous method inside of a click event delay to much to update a label

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello i have problem updating a label text with an eventhandler and an asynchronous method.

**Function that creates a directory and update the label**

```
private void buttonFolderMakeDir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBoxFolderPath.Text != string.Empty)
            {
                CreateDirForm createDirDialog = new CreateDirForm();

                if (createDirDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(createDirDialog.DirName) == true)
                        {
                            // Read the contents of testDialog's TextBox.
                            string path = textBoxFolderPath.Text + "\\" + createDirDialog.DirName;
                            DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                            if (di.Exists)
                            {
                                buttonFolderRefresh_Click(null, null);
                                labelStatusFolder.Text = "Directorio : " + createDirDialog.DirName + " creado con exito. Time: " + GetTime();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                labelStatusFolder.Text = "Erro directorio : " + createDirDialog.DirName + " ya existe. Time: " + GetTime();
                            }
                        }   
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error al crear directorio.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                }
                createDirDialog.Dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error debe seleccionar una ruta de archivos.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

After the directory is created. This two lines of code will be executed

```
buttonFolderRefresh_Click(null, null);
labelStatusFolder.Text = "Directorio : " + createDirDialog.DirName + " creado con exito. Time: " + GetTime();
```

**buttonFolderRefresh_Click** is an eventhandker click button with an asynchronous method inside that updates the **labelStatusFolder**, the problem is that the eventhandler function updates the **labelStatusFolder** after the **buttonFolderMakeDir_Click** function do it in a synchronous way. So i don't get the last message update.

**buttonFolderRefresh_Click** function

```
private void buttonFolderRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBoxFolderPath.Text != string.Empty)
            {
                ListFolder(textBoxFolderPath.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error debe seleccionar una ruta de archivos.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

**ListFolder** function.

```
private async void ListFolder(string folderPath)
        {
            Tuple <bool, string> result = await Task.Run(() => FillListFolder.FillFromPath(folderPath));
            if (result.Item1)
            {
                listBoxFolderFill();
                labelStatusFolder.Text = "Directorio listado correctamente. Time: " + GetTime();
            }
            else
            {
                listViewFolder.Items.Clear();
                ConcurrentListOperations.EmptyList(ConcunrrentFilesFolder.FolderList);
                textBoxFolderPath.Text = "Error";
                labelStatusFolder.Text = "Error al listar directorio. Time: " + GetTime();
                MessageBox.Show("Mensaje: " + result.Item2, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

Thank you

Comment: Make `async void ListFolder` an  `async Task ListFolder` _and await it_.

Comment: @Fildor thanks. I added it and change the buttonFolderRefresh_Click(null, null); for ListFolder()